# InvalidAccessKeyId Error when Configuring AWS CLI Access Keys as Env Vars

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I am creating a Node application that avails of Amazon Web Service(AWS) through an AWS Educate account. I am doing this with the Command Line Interface(CLI). I am certain that I am using up to date keys(as both the public and private keys expire every 3 hours).

When I run the command

```
aws configure list
```

my terminal returns the following

```
      Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************X34V              env    
secret_key     ****************QO41              env    
    region                us-east-1      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

which are the values I was expecting.

However, when I try to run my application with

```
node app.js
```

I receive the following error from my terminal

```
InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
    at Request.extractError (/Users/conogolaoghaire/Desktop/MyCloudApplication/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:700:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/conogolaoghaire/Desktop/MyCloudApplication/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/Users/conogolaoghaire/Desktop/MyCloudApplication/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/conogolaoghaire/Desktop/MyCloudApplication/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/Users/conogolaoghaire/Desktop/MyCloudApplication/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/conogolaoghaire/Desktop/MyCloudApplication/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /Users/conogolaoghaire/Desktop/MyCloudApplication/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/conogolaoghaire/Desktop/MyCloudApplication/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/conogolaoghaire/Desktop/MyCloudApplication/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/conogolaoghaire/Desktop/MyCloudApplication/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  message: 'The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.',
  code: 'InvalidAccessKeyId',
  region: null,
  time: 2020-12-06T20:01:47.904Z,
  requestId: 'A16828D1DD5EFED2',
  extendedRequestId: 'gFmtQ01H7WOz9zXgcs9KvzOJm+H/HIESxCBEawqQQSEI+n65SaD3qf7ZoO/b32/u2mmzXW9qPD0=',
  cfId: undefined,
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 25.661256628068287
} InvalidAccessKeyId: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
    at Request.extractError (/Users/conogolaoghaire/Desktop/MyCloudApplication/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:700:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/conogolaoghaire/Desktop/MyCloudApplication/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/Users/conogolaoghaire/Desktop/MyCloudApplication/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/conogolaoghaire/Desktop/MyCloudApplication/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/Users/conogolaoghaire/Desktop/MyCloudApplication/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/conogolaoghaire/Desktop/MyCloudApplication/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /Users/conogolaoghaire/Desktop/MyCloudApplication/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/conogolaoghaire/Desktop/MyCloudApplication/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/conogolaoghaire/Desktop/MyCloudApplication/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/conogolaoghaire/Desktop/MyCloudApplication/server/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
```

I have specified my keys as environment variables, in the relevant app.js file, and in my ~/.aws/credentials file.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, I had also defined the keys in my app.js file. Subsequent to that in this file I would use the keys like this:

```
aws.config.update({
    accessKeyId: publicKey,
    secretAccessKey: privateKey
})
```

Deleting the above code solved my error and allowed me to access AWS. I don't know why.